# Capture HTTP requests for reply

Tags: linux, http

Is there a tool that I can run on a Linux server that will let me capture an HTTP request from my production environment and then be able to replay those requests on my staging environment to make sure the new code and server are able to handle the number of requests.

Comment: It seems like you are looking for a proxy !?

Comment: See http://articles.mongueurs.net/magazines/perles/perles-43.html it's French, but it's Perl too ;)